# Message Queue, Kafka, Event System as "database" for an advert site?

Tags: redis, apache-kafka, rabbitmq

I'm researching with a friend about the idea of using an event queue/stream system, such as kafka or rabbitmq, as a way to store the adverts in a queue instead of a traditional database.

The required system would need to provide a stream of events holding various fields, be filterable and searchable. Allow the stream to hold the events indefinitely or for a certain amount of time (for example to let the adverts expire). We are just not sure whether to go for a message queue/event stream, or whether the traditional database is the way to go.

Has anybody experience with this, would you recommend to investigate one system over another?

Comment: *Opinionated answer* - Kafka can very easily do this. If you use a compacted topic, it's essentially the same as a database transaction log. Avro allows you to easily define a schema for each record and you can use a Schema Registry to enforce valid schema changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka would support the usecase, as you can treat it not as messaging queue, but as a transaction log:

- you can re-read the same message multiple times with different consumers
- the messages would be persisted until they expire (configurable on server) or until they are compacted
- (data propagation) there are tools such as mirror maker (or own streaming applications) to replicate data among data centres (or some part of them, e.g. if you decide to put some attributes in one topic, and other in another)

I do not know if generic messaging solution (like RabbitMQ) would suit you, as messages consumed would disappear, so you would need to re-publish them to keep them (and in case of multiple consumers, you'd need to use RMQ logic like fanout exchanges that messages get multicasted to multiple queues, each per consumer).